# Flink error with 'The implementation of the StreamExecutionEnvironment is not serializable'

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am a beginner of Flink, and I tried to use Flink to run LFM, one of the recommended algorithms, but the following errors appeared in my code when it was running. I tried to find and modify them, but they were not solved. Could someone tell me why I had problems?

**Here are my main exception**

```
The implementation of the StreamExecutionEnvironment is not serializable
```

**And my code here**

Noted that `sourceDataStream` is from my custom source extends `RichFunction<Tuple3<>>`

```java
//training model
for (int iter = 0; iter < iterations; iter++) {
    sourceDataStream
        // the exception appears here
        .process(new ProcessFunction<Tuple3<String, String, Double>, Object>() {
            @Override
            public void processElement(Tuple3<String, String, Double> in,
                                                   ProcessFunction<Tuple3<String, String, Double>, Object>.Context context,
                                                   Collector<Object> collector) throws Exception {

                Double hat_rui = predict(in.f0, in.f1, qbiTable, pbuTable, streamTableEnvironment);
                Double err_ui = in.f2 - hat_rui;
                Table pbuSelectTable = pbuTable.select($("buValue"), $("pList")).where($("userId").isEqual(in.f0));
                Table qbiSelectTable = qbiTable.select($("biValue"), $("qList")).where($("itemId").isEqual(in.f1));

                DataStream<Tuple2<Boolean, Tuple2<Double, List<Double>>>> pbuSelectDataStream = streamTableEnvironment.toRetractStream(pbuSelectTable, new TupleTypeInfo<>(Types.BOOLEAN, Types.DOUBLE, Types.LIST(Types.DOUBLE)));
                pbuSelectDataStream.process(new ProcessFunction<Tuple2<Boolean, Tuple2<Double, List<Double>>>, Object>() {

                @Override
                public void processElement(Tuple2<Boolean, Tuple2<Double, List<Double>>> userTuple,
                                                           ProcessFunction<Tuple2<Boolean, Tuple2<Double, List<Double>>>, Object>.Context context,
                                                           Collector<Object> collector) throws Exception {

                    DataStream<Tuple2<Boolean, Tuple2<Double, List<Double>>>> qbiSelectDataStream = streamTableEnvironment.toRetractStream(qbiSelectTable, new TupleTypeInfo<>(Types.BOOLEAN, Types.DOUBLE, Types.LIST(Types.DOUBLE)));
                    qbiSelectDataStream.process(new ProcessFunction<Tuple2<Boolean, Tuple2<Double, List<Double>>>, Object>() {

                        @Override
                        public void processElement(Tuple2<Boolean, Tuple2<Double, List<Double>>> itemTuple, ProcessFunction<Tuple2<Boolean, Tuple2<Double, List<Double>>>, Object>.Context context, Collector<Object> collector) throws Exception {

                            double bu = userTuple.f1.f0 + (alpha * (err_ui - lambd * userTuple.f1.f0));
                            double bi = itemTuple.f1.f0 + (alpha * (err_ui - lambd * itemTuple.f1.f0));

                            List<Double> pList = new ArrayList<>();
                            List<Double> qList = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (int fIter = 0; fIter < F; fIter++) {
                                Double pValueLast = userTuple.f1.f1.get(fIter);
                                Double qValueLast = itemTuple.f1.f1.get(fIter);
                                Double qValueNew = qValueLast + (alpha * (err_ui * pValueLast - lambd * qValueLast));
                                Double pValueNew = pValueLast + (alpha * (err_ui * qValueLast - lambd * pValueLast));
                                pList.add(pValueNew);
                                qList.add(qValueNew);
                            }
                            streamTableEnvironment.executeSql("INSERT OVERWRITE qbiTable VALUES ('qList', " + qList + "), ('biValue', " + bi + ")");
                            streamTableEnvironment.executeSql("INSERT OVERWRITE pbuTable VALUES ('pList', " + pList + "), ('buValue', " + bu + ")");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things about this that aren't going to work:

In the implementation of any user function (such as a `ProcessFunction`) you cannot have a `DataStream`, or a `Table`, or a `StreamExecutionEnvironment`, or another `ProcessFunction`. All you can do is react to an incoming stream record, optionally using state you have built up inside that function based on the previously processed records.

The `DataStream` and `Table` APIs are organized around a builder paradigm, with which you are describing a streaming dataflow pipeline. This pipeline must be a directed acyclic graph: it can split and merge but must flow from sources to sinks without any loops. The stages of that pipeline (e.g., a `ProcessFunction`) must be coded as independent blocks -- they cannot reach outside of themselves to access data from other pipeline stages.

This paradigm isn't well suited for the purpose of training machine learning models (since training involves iterating/looping). If that's your objective, maybe take a look at https://github.com/apache/flink-ml.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try it later.